What are some ways of storing some chemicals under inert gas that aren't too expensive or space consuming?
I will order a reagent that is hydroscopic and recommended to be stored under inert gas.
I suppose something like a glovebox is best but I would like to exploe some alternative options that are a bit less expensive and easier to set up at a desk.
The main option I have in mind is a glass desiccator which is typically used with a vacuum (the type with two hemispheres of heavy glass). I suppose I could keep it under vacuum, but would it also work to vacuum it out, then backfill with N2?
Any there any other suggestions?

Nitrogen purged drybox?

Likely, that would work -- with multiple purges. of vacuum/N2, to rid any O2/H2O left in lines.

@JonCuster, can you elaborate on what you mean by drybox? Like one I would store camera equipment in?

Argon too, if it's available

@user668074 - Google for "nitrogen dry box" - a plastic (or stainless) box with house nitrogen purge.
